# How to resolve "Access denied for user 'drngpasc'@'localhost'" Error?

Tags: php

Hai Alex

Thank you for your answer.One more error as follow:

> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: Access
>   denied for user 'drngpasc'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ngp\connect.php on
>   line 2
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db()
>   [function.mysql-select-db]: Access
>   denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ngp\connect.php on
>   line 4
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db()
>   [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to
>   the server could not be established in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ngp\connect.php on
>   line 4

Answer (score 0):

The first and second errors means that you have a mistake in connection config. May be you use wrong login or password to db. Check you database config, may be connect with this login is denied for example.

The third error means that you want to select databse, but you not connected to database server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your user ID and password to login to MySQL. If its a local WAMP/LAMP setup - try user:root pass:(blank)   user:root pass:root.

Answer (score 0):

Is MySQL installed and running? Do you have a user account drngpasc on your local MySQL install. Do you have a password on that account (if you have an account, yes you have a password in this case).